# reactJs update state object without overwriting the object

Tags: reactjs

I am having problems updating an object in this.state. Basically I have a form with multiple range sliders. Each time the slider is changed I want to update the this.state.dreadModel object, however I only seem to be able to overwrite it.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
this.setState( update ( this.state.dreadModel, { dreadModel: { [name]: e.target.value } } ), function () {
  console.log(this.state);
});
```

The error I get with the above code is "Uncaught ReferenceError: update is not defined".

I feel like I am very close, but I cant quite get the syntax quite right.

Oh, here is the code I was using that would just overwrite the object each time a sliders value was changed.

```
this.setState({ dreadModel: {[name]: e.target.value }}, function () {
  console.log(this.state);
});
```

Comment: from where does `update` function came from?

Comment: `update` is not defined because it is [not included in React by default](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html); you need to install an addon: `var update = require('react-addons-update');`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I usually do if I need to update a nested object, is something more like:

```
var dreadModel = {...this.state.dreadModel, [name]: e.target.value };
//or, if no ES6:
//var dreadModel = Object.assign({}, this.state.dreadModel);
//dreadModel[name] = e.target.value;
this.setState({ dreadModel: dreadModel }, function () {
    console.log(this.state);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I cannot believe I didn't see this solution, it looks like I was just getting deeper and deeper into a really complicated solution when there was a much simpler one available to me if I had just stepped back a bit. Thanks for your help.

Comment: this is mutating the state object, which you are not supposed to do

Comment: This works but I'd say it's a bit of an anti-pattern because you are mutating `this.state`. You could copy the object instead like `var dreadModel = { ...this.state.dreadModel }` then modify `dreadModel`...